# Download the information from a google spreadsheet in JSON format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I am downloading the information from a google spreadsheet in JSON format from the google page https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet

Adding the ID of the sheet (spreadsheetId) and the range of rows (ranges), for example A1: C3, I download the JSON of the spreadsheet fine:

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": "1CzOCgJ9TT_ZX4YT0ACQI1q8Lh3tBF6knvnV",
  "valueRanges": [
    {
      "range": "'Test'!A1:C3",
      "majorDimension": "ROWS",
      "values": [
        [
          "ID",
          "NAME",
          "LAST"
        ],
        [
          "111",
          "PROFILE1",
          "DATE 1"
        ],
        [
          "222",
          "PROFILE2",
          "DATE 2"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I have the following doubts:

1. In the range I am specifying the cells I want, but is it possible to specify the entire spreadsheet? That is, even if I add more information, the range will continue to pick it up because it is indicated to read the entire spreadsheet
2. My spreadsheet has more than 1 sheet, how can I specify the sheet from which to extract the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put in the id of the spreadsheet

In the ranges section you put something like Sheet0!A1:J then you push the plus button and put something like Sheet1!A1:J

My return was:

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": "",
  "valueRanges": [
    {
      "range": "Sheet0!A1:J982",
      "majorDimension": "ROWS",
      "values": [
        [
          "COL1",
          "COL2",
          "COL3",
          "COL4",
          "COL5",
          "COL6",
          "COL7",
          "COL8",
          "COL9",
          "COL10"
        ],
        [
          "13",
          "16",
          "9",
          "12",
          "19",
          "8",
          "1",
          "18",
          "5",
          "1"
        ],
        [
          "16",
          "19",
          "5",
          "16",
          "2",
          "12",
          "5",
          "2",
          "8",
          "2"
        ],
        [
          "12",
          "7",
          "2",
          "10",
          "18",
          "17",
          "15",
          "12",
          "15",
          "2"
        ],
        [
          "1",
          "3",
          "17",
          "8",
          "10",
          "7",
          "5",
          "14",
          "18",
          "7"
        ],
        [
          "13",
          "16",
          "7",
          "15",
          "14",
          "5",
          "8",
          "15",
          "8",
          "19"
        ],
        [
          "15",
          "0",
          "3",
          "6",
          "12",
          "4",
          "6",
          "15",
          "15",
          "17"
        ],
        [
          "8",
          "18",
          "4",
          "16",
          "11",
          "8",
          "14",
          "5",
          "18",
          "6"
        ],
        [
          "5",
          "2",
          "6",
          "7",
          "1",
          "10",
          "1",
          "5",
          "14",
          "3"
        ],
        [
          "11",
          "19",
          "1",
          "6",
          "16",
          "13",
          "2",
          "9",
          "14",
          "2"
        ],
        [
          "16",
          "11",
          "9",
          "3",
          "17",
          "19",
          "14",
          "12",
          "14",
          "0"
        ],
        [
          "16",
          "6",
          "19",
          "17",
          "15",
          "10",
          "13",
          "12",
          "0",
          "1"
        ],
        [
          "8",
          "13",
          "1",
          "18",
          "8",
          "4",
          "17",
          "17",
          "10",
          "13"
        ],
        [
          "12",
          "16",
          "0",
          "0",
          "15",
          "11",
          "3",
          "4",
          "19",
          "9"
        ],
        [
          "9",
          "3",
          "8",
          "17",
          "14",
          "0",
          "12",
          "4",
          "4",
          "6"
        ],
        [
          "16",
          "5",
          "8",
          "16",
          "3",
          "0",
          "13",
          "10",
          "2",
          "8"
        ],
        [
          "11",
          "9",
          "6",
          "6",
          "18",
          "4",
          "0",
          "19",
          "2",
          "15"
        ],
        [
          "2",
          "0",
          "5",
          "7",
          "8",
          "8",
          "16",
          "12",
          "1",
          "12"
        ],
        [
          "2",
          "6",
          "7",
          "2",
          "16",
          "18",
          "15",
          "19",
          "13",
          "8"
        ],
        [
          "4",
          "0",
          "0",
          "6",
          "11",
          "4",
          "9",
          "7",
          "1",
          "1"
        ],
        [
          "17",
          "0",
          "17",
          "8",
          "7",
          "11",
          "10",
          "0",
          "16",
          "1"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "range": "Sheet1!A1:J1002",
      "majorDimension": "ROWS",
      "values": [
        [
          "COL1",
          "COL2",
          "COL3",
          "COL4",
          "COL5",
          "COL6",
          "COL7",
          "COL8",
          "COL9",
          "COL10"
        ],
        [
          "4",
          "5",
          "12",
          "6",
          "13",
          "10",
          "17",
          "9",
          "13",
          "4"
        ],
        [
          "13",
          "12",
          "15",
          "7",
          "10",
          "4",
          "14",
          "6",
          "17",
          "12"
        ],
        [
          "0",
          "13",
          "11",
          "7",
          "12",
          "6",
          "0",
          "0",
          "13",
          "14"
        ],
        [
          "15",
          "5",
          "5",
          "4",
          "15",
          "1",
          "7",
          "8",
          "2",
          "4"
        ],
        [
          "1",
          "4",
          "15",
          "5",
          "5",
          "5",
          "8",
          "18",
          "3",
          "19"
        ],
        [
          "3",
          "11",
          "14",
          "9",
          "14",
          "3",
          "15",
          "19",
          "6",
          "15"
        ],
        [
          "9",
          "13",
          "19",
          "19",
          "7",
          "17",
          "18",
          "17",
          "8",
          "6"
        ],
        [
          "11",
          "8",
          "16",
          "5",
          "13",
          "7",
          "19",
          "12",
          "0",
          "9"
        ],
        [
          "6",
          "15",
          "18",
          "15",
          "12",
          "5",
          "18",
          "6",
          "8",
          "10"
        ],
        [
          "2",
          "3",
          "3",
          "17",
          "8",
          "8",
          "8",
          "17",
          "19",
          "0"
        ],
        [
          "4",
          "7",
          "5",
          "4",
          "17",
          "0",
          "18",
          "0",
          "14",
          "4"
        ],
        [
          "18",
          "16",
          "9",
          "12",
          "4",
          "18",
          "3",
          "13",
          "18",
          "0"
        ],
        [
          "11",
          "3",
          "18",
          "4",
          "9",
          "4",
          "19",
          "5",
          "15",
          "18"
        ],
        [
          "16",
          "8",
          "11",
          "7",
          "0",
          "14",
          "1",
          "1",
          "8",
          "6"
        ],
        [
          "6",
          "7",
          "4",
          "19",
          "0",
          "17",
          "1",
          "3",
          "10",
          "4"
        ],
        [
          "19",
          "8",
          "3",
          "7",
          "7",
          "14",
          "19",
          "16",
          "4",
          "2"
        ],
        [
          "6",
          "16",
          "15",
          "15",
          "18",
          "17",
          "6",
          "17",
          "18",
          "0"
        ],
        [
          "16",
          "13",
          "1",
          "19",
          "9",
          "10",
          "3",
          "17",
          "0",
          "18"
        ],
        [
          "0",
          "11",
          "4",
          "12",
          "3",
          "0",
          "16",
          "17",
          "18",
          "1"
        ],
        [
          "15",
          "3",
          "0",
          "2",
          "6",
          "2",
          "9",
          "3",
          "10",
          "4"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Fortunately, it only returns data in the data range not the entire mostly empty spreadsheet.

Comment: I don't want to do it in the code, I just want to get the JSON from the page that I have tested. But I don't know how to put the range of the whole sheet and how to choose another sheet

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: JSON is an acronym for JavaScript Object Notation() so it's something used in Javascript code and since Google Apps Script is a server side form of JavaScript it also uses JSON.  So getting the JSON of a sheet implies the use of code.

Comment: Try to enter the URL that I have put in the question. A series of options appear, in the spreadsheetId field you put the ID of the spreadsheet and in the ranges field the range of cells you want to show. What I want to know is how to choose another sheet or range the entire sheet.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you were asking.

Comment: Ok yes, putting the name of the sheet that I want if you read it

Comment: How can I get all the fields? I have tried adding fields * to the field, but I don't get anything